# Optimization: Class using less memory

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a C++ class that has functions that return objects:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  int m_v1;
  double m_v2;
  ObjA m_obA;
  ObjB m_obB;
  std::string m_s1;

  std::vector< float > foo();

public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();

  int foo2();
  double foo3();
  ObjA foo4();
};
```

I know that reorganising the members in descending order of the type, the memory used will be smaller. If it is the same for the function members, how should I organize it the best way?

Comment: The member functions don't affect the class' size or layout. At least not for a class with no virtual members.

Comment: And if there are virtual members, than the order those virtual members are declared determines which slot they get.

Comment: You don't follow your own rule, int should be after double!

Comment: @Deduplicator the order that virtual methods are declared  *in the base class* or the first derived class in which they are declared determines the order of the methods in the vtable.  And this info has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: if by "descending order of the type" you mean "alignment constraint (weaker or stronger, doesn't matter)", then you get it packed well. (actually, if you have a polymorphic type, increasing will likely be easier).

Comment: @DaleWilson: How is the vtable layout (if there is one) not part of the class layout, even if it does not change the object size?

Comment: @juanchopanza I have said memory used; so when you run the application you will see that it uses more or less memory based on the order of the members declaration in the class. And I was asking if this is the same for the functions that return a value [see this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Code_optimization/Faster_operations)

Answer (score 0):

As @juanchopanza pointed out non-virtual member functions don't affect the size of the object.

In 'most all implementations of C++, the FIRST virtual method increases object size by sizeof(pointer).  Additional methods (virtual or otherwise) have no impact on object size.